# Loop for copying, pasting and saving the form

Tags: excel, vba

I am filling an Excel form by copying data from rows of this Excel workbook.
NJT Copy workbook
[image]

and pasting the data in this Excel form.
NJT Voucher
[image]

For copying and pasting data of single row and saving a single form, I used the following VBA code.

```vb
Workbooks("NJT COPY").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C2").Copy
Workbooks("NJT VOUCHER").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("E4").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

Workbooks("NJT COPY").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("D2").Copy
Workbooks("NJT VOUCHER").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B4").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues


Workbooks("NJT COPY").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("H2").Copy
Workbooks("NJT VOUCHER").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("F41").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

Workbooks("NJT COPY").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("I2").Copy
Workbooks("NJT VOUCHER").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("F5").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
  
  
Workbooks("NJT VOUCHER").SaveAs _
Filename:="C:\Users\computer\Documents\file\vouc1"
Workbooks("vouc1").Close
```

How can I put my code in a loop that automatically fills the form (NJT VOUCHER) for each row from "NJT COPY" workbook and saves each form with different name?

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub RunLoop()

For i = 1 to 50
Call CopyPasteClose
Next i

End Sub



Sub CopyPasteClose()

Dim WB1 As Workbook
Dim WB2 As Workbook
Dim WS1 As Worksheet
Dim WS2 As Worksheet
Dim Filename As String

Set WB1 = Workbooks("NJT COPY")
Set WB2 = Workbooks("NJT VOUCHER")
Set WS1 = WB1.Sheets("Sheet1")
Set WS2 = WB2.Sheets("Sheet1")

Filename = "C:\Users\computer\Documents\file\vouc1"

With WS2
.Range("E4").Value = WS1.Range("C2").Value
.Range("B4").Value = WS1.Range("D2").Value
.Range("F41").Value = WS1.Range("H2").Value
.Range("F5").Value = WS1.Range("I2").Value
End With

With WB2
.SaveAs Filename
.Close
End With
 
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks you for the clean code. Is there a way I can run this on loop. I have more than 50 forms to fill from the data on another worksheet. I want to save each form separately.

Comment: I’ve added in an extra subroutine which runs the main code multiple times. Hopefully this is what you’re looking for.

Comment: The loop runs only once for the cells that are in the code and save only one From. I want it to get data from each row and fill the separate form for each row and save them. Thank you for the help, I appreciate it.